# Solve the PDE using characteristics method

Tags: partial-differential-equations, homogeneous-equation, characteristics

Consider the PDE $$3 \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}} + t^2\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} = 0: t \lt 0 $$

with the initial condition $$u(x,0) = f(x): 0 \lt x \lt 1$$

Determine the characteristics and sketch them.

I understand that the PDE is of the semi-linear homogenous form but i'm struggling with the method.

So far I have $\frac{\partial{t}}{\partial{\sigma}} = 3$, $\frac{\partial{x}}{\partial{\sigma}} = t^2$ and $\frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{\sigma}} = 0$.

$\Rightarrow t = 3\sigma + t_0, x = t^2\sigma+ x_0, z = z_0$.

But I don't understand how to proceed and incorporate the initial conditions too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$3 \frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{t}} + t^2\frac{\partial{u}}{\partial{x}} = 0$$
The characteristic relationships are :
$$\frac{dt}{3}=\frac{dx}{t^2}=\frac{du}{0}$$
A first characteristic results from $\frac{dt}{3}=\frac{dx}{t^2} \qquad\to\qquad dx-\frac{1}{3}t^2 dt=0$
$$x-\frac{1}{9}t^3=c_1$$
A second characteristic results from necessarily $du=0$ :
$$u=c_2$$
Thus, the general solution expressed on implicite form is :
$$\Phi\left(x-\frac{1}{9}t^3\:,\:u\right)=0$$
where $\Phi$ is any differentiable function of two variables.

This implicite equation can be solved for $u$ :
$$u=F\left(x-\frac{1}{9}t^3\right)$$
where $F$ is any differentiable function of one variable.

The boundary condition :
$$u(x,0)=f(x)$$
where $f(x)$ is a given function, leads to :
$$f(x)=F\left(x-\frac{1}{9}0^3\right)=F(x)$$
which determines $F(x)=f(x)$

So, the final result is :
$$u(x,t)=f\left(x-\frac{1}{9}t^3\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth and clear solution. I'm just curious as to how the implicite equation would be solved for u?

Comment: In such an equation $\Phi(X,Y)=0$ since $\Phi$ is any function, one variable is any function of the other. For example $Y=F(X)$ any function $F$.